# How to get changes ftom master to branch (only those that touch the branch)?

Tags: git

There is a branch 'feature' how I can take from the 'master' branch only those changes that apply to my branch?

`git merge master` take all changes, but I only need changes that affect my branch.

Comment: Have you looked at `git cherry-pick` ?

Comment: In terms of commits and commit trees, what  do you mean exactly by “affect my branch”?

Comment: Why do you want to pick up changes from an upstream branch that ( I assume) only affect files you have changed in your branch (since you diverged)? I mean, a rebase is quite a fast operation.

Comment: Suppose someone changed the code in the same file that I'm working on in my branch, but also in his commit a bunch of other changes I don't need. I need to take the changes just from that file and merge them with my branch.

Comment: Why do you care? No harm is done by the "all changes" appearing in your branch.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I mean When I try to do a 'git merge master' I get lots of modified files in my branch in the commit that don't relate to changes in my branch. That is, I get all the differences between my branch and the master branch, but I only need to get changes from a few files from master into my branch.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly, this is just a visual issue. You want to declutter your view from irrelevant files in order to, for example, review only the relevant ones together as a group, right?

Comment: If so, someone can provide a composite bash command to identify the commits for the changed files and `cherry-pick -n` them. But you have to understand, that cherry-picking changes partially might compromise the integrity of your app. It can stop working, and the only way to fix it would be to revert all new changes, undoing the progress.

Comment: Cherry pick doesn't look like a good fit, but maybe that's because I'm not good with git. I'll try to figure it out anyway thanks a lot to everyone who helps.

Comment: Taking changes only on some files and leaving the others out is _not_ the way to go.... even if you are cherry-picking, given that the patch is a whole unit... it's more than likely that changes on your files will _need_ changes from the other files as well (it might not be the case, but it's _unlikely_).

Comment: Well, the thing is that git works with commits, not files. Unfortunately, there is no correlation between commits and files. One commit can span several files, or one file, or be a partial (WIP) change, or be a self-sufficient change.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to `git merge --no-commit --no-ff master`

Once the merge is done (but not yet committed), you can `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M HEAD..master` to list files, and, for those which were not modified in `feature`, you can restore them: `git restore -s feature -- afile`.

Comment: Man, this is a recipe for disaster as there might be changes applied on those files you are taking back that are required by the changes in the files your are keeping. It is much safer to pull (cherry-pick, of course) individual commits.

Comment: @eftshift0 cherry-picking commits will potentially include changes from master for files which were not modified in feature, which is what the OP wants to avoid, if I understand the question correctly.